# Выражение "Федот, да не тот"

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Откуда пошло это выражение и что оно означает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так говорят о том, кто оказывается не тем, за кого его принимали. Как правило, хуже.
Дело в том, что в святцах аж девять именин Федота. Но большая их часть приходится на посты. Разумеется, в это время ни о каких празднованиях именин и речи идти не могло, так что, везло тем Федотам, чьи именины приходились на время между постами, а особенно, на Масленицу.